# 1-8-1 Beep Error on P43Twins1600 mobo

Tags: boot, motherboard, hardware-failure

My friend picked up a pretty new diablotak 850w power supply on the belief that his system is down because of it, but it still isn't booting. I removed everything I could, so now we just have an intel processor and one gig of ram - which all were working before - but the thing won't come online. Any ideas? I'm not even getting to a bios screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to page 15 of the [AMIBIOS8 Checkpoint and Beep Code List](http://www.ami.com/support/doc/AMIBIOS8_Checkpoint_and_Beep_Code_List_PUB.pdf), which applies to the BIOS this ASRock motherboard uses, eight beeps means:

> Display memory error (system video adapter)

The video card is faulty.  If you have another graphics adapter, you can try installing it to see if this solves this problem.  If this fails, the motherboard will likely need to be replaced.  The beep code list says:

> If the system video adapter is an add-in card, replace or reseat the video adapter. If the video adapter is an integrated part of the system board, the board may be faulty.

Comment: +1 for awesome immediacy and great link! Thanks.